# FlipView button Invisible on touch Surface

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, flipview

I am using FlipView Control in windows store app to navigate on different screen. The button of flipView are visible but auto hide after some time on laptop(OS: windows 8 or 8.1) while running app but not visible on windows tablet ( touch surface). How to make button visible on touch surface too

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the built in next/prev buttons, they only show up after a pointer is moved on the page(and only if there is a next or prev item to go to). On the surface or any touch screen you don't need them because you can swipe to the next or previous page.

Try running the built in photos viewer app, it uses a FlipView and behaves exactly like this.

Comment: Thank You Jon. But if there is requirement to make them visible always, then how we can override control's button behaviour?